# MySQL and PHP - make href remember previous variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am quite new to PHP, but come with some knowledge of JavaScript.

I am trying to construct a MySQL table which has sortable columns by header, which I managed figure out through looking around the web, etc; but then wanted the SQL query to use a WHERE clause which only shows rows that meet that clause (and it works), but the problem is that when I then sort the columns it goes back to the original value of the $catergory variable.

I hope that makes sense.

Could somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong and either if I need to change the SQL query or find a way to get the PHP to remember the reassigned value of $catergory, when I want to sort the columns afterwards?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("host","user","password","database") or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($con));

$categoryFilter = array('boardroom', 'staffroom', 'kitchen');

$category = 'boardroom';
if (isset($_GET['categoryFilter']) && in_array($_GET['categoryFilter'], $categoryFilter)) {
    $category = $_GET['categoryFilter'];
}

$orderBy = array('Image', 'Description', 'Light', 'Room');

$order = 'Image';
if (isset($_GET['orderBy']) && in_array($_GET['orderBy'], $orderBy)) {
    $order = $_GET['orderBy'];
}   

?>

<div class="catbuttons">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="?categoryFilter=boardroom">Boardroom</a></li>
        <li style="height: 17px"><a href="?categoryFilter=staffroom">Staffroom</a></li>
        <li><a href="?categoryFilter=kitchen">Kitchen</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="index">

<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th><a href="?orderBy=Image&categoryFilter=<?php echo($category);?>">Image</a></th>
<th><a href="?orderBy=Description&categoryFilter=<?php echo($category);?>">Description</a></th>
<th><a href="?orderBy=Light&categoryFilter=<?php echo($category);?>">Light</a></th>
<th><a href="?orderBy=Room&categoryFilter=<?php echo($category);?>">Room</a></th>
</tr>


<?php


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM officeindex WHERE Room='".$category."' ORDER BY ".$order)
  or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" , $row['Image'] , "</td>";
  echo "<td>" , $row['Description'] , "</td>";
  echo "<td><img src='" , $row['Light'] , "'></td>";
  echo "<td>" , $row['Room'] , "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

**EDIT:**

Thank you everyone, I have implemented your suggested solutions to my original question and changed the code above, but I am now having further difficulty. The purpose of my code is to construct an interactive product list of sorts. Now that I have the categories (thanks for pointing out the spelling mistake) working, I want the table, at first, to show all the categories, i.e. all the products in the list, before the user clicks on a specific category.

The other problem is that I can't work out what to do about cells which contain multiple categories (Some products fall into multiple categories).

I've thought about using arrays or loops or booleans or some kind to do both of the above, but my knowledge is limited to JavaScript and I'm a bit lost in PHP, even though there are similarities. Please forgive my ignorance.

I hope I have explained this clearly

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: It's a good use to replace double quotes by simple quotes if you don't have to put variable in your string. It's slower for PHP to interprete "string" than 'string'. And prefere use the multiple parametre of echo in place of the string concatenation. (echo 'hello', 'world'; better than echo 'hello'.'world';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links in your tableheader only contain the orderBy parameter. If you want to keep the categoryFilter, you need to include it in the href of your headers.

For example:

```
<tr>
    <th><a href="?orderBy=Image&catergoryFilter=<?php echo($catergory);?>">Image</a></th>
    <th><a href="?orderBy=Description&catergoryFilter=<?php echo($catergory);?>">Description</a></th>
    <th><a href="?orderBy=Light&catergoryFilter=<?php echo($catergory);?>">Light</a></th>
    <th><a href="?orderBy=Room&catergoryFilter=<?php echo($catergory);?>">Room</a></th>
</tr>
```

For the category filter it's the other way around of course:

```
<li><a href="?catergoryFilter=boardroom&orderBy=<?php echo($order);?>">Boardroom</a></li>
<li><a href="?catergoryFilter=staffroom&orderBy=<?php echo($order);?>">Staffroom</a></li>
<li><a href="?catergoryFilter=kitchen&orderBy=<?php echo($order);?>">Kitchen</a></li>
```

Also, as @K.K.Smith pointed out, you might want to replace **catergory** with **category**

Comment: Take care about the '<?='. It's not a regular begining tag of php script. View W3C standards

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin thanks for pointing that out, I didn't know php short tags are deprecated.

Comment: But i don't know why :-) it's really better to see than an horrible echo !

Comment: I'll just be "that guy" to say your spelling "category" wrong.  Could cause problems.

Comment: @K.K.Smith actually I spellt "catergory" wrong, since that is the actual name of the php variable - but thanks for pointing it out, made me double check ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your links, You have to put the varaibles if they exists.

Example :

```
<a href="?categoryFilter=staffroom<?php if isset($_GET['orderBy'] echo '&orderBy=", $_GET['orderBy'];?>" />
```